# How to use awk to count the occurence of a word beginning with something?

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
**FID IID**
1   RQ50131-0
2   469314
3   469704
4   469712
5   RQ50135-2
6   469720
7   470145
```

I want to use awk to count the occurences of IDs beginning with 'RQ' in column 2.
So for the little snapshot, it should be 2. After the RQ, the numbers differ so I want a count with anything that begins with RQ.

I am using this code

```
awk -F '\t' '{if(match("^RQ$",$2))print}'|wc -l  ID.txt > RQ.txt
```

But I don't get an output.

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are used as field delimiters by default (same as spaces), so you can omit `-F '\t'`.

You can use

```sh
awk '$2 ~ /^RQ/{cnt++} END{print cnt}' ID.txt > RQ.txt
```

Once Field 2 starts with `RQ`, increment `cnt` and once the file is processed print `cnt`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/5fFbPw).

Answer (score 2):

You did

```
{if(match("^RQ$",$2))print}
```

but compulsory arguments to [`match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function are string, regexp. Also do not use `$` if you are interesting in finding strings starting with as `$` denotes end. After fixing that issues code would be

```
{if(match($2,"^RQ"))print}
```

Disclaimer: this answer does describe solely fixing problems with your current code, it does not contain any ways to ameliorate your code.

Answer (score 0):

Also apart from the reversed parameters for match, the file `ID.txt` should come right after the closing single quote.

As you want to print the whole line, you can omit the if statement and the print statement because match returns the index at which that substring begins, or 0 if there is no match.

```
awk 'match($2,"^RQ")' ID.txt | wc -l > RQ.txt
```